# Helicon Ape redirects don't work as expected in Sitefinity 3.7

Tags: .net, iis-7, iis-6, sitefinity, helicontech

We are migrating an old Sitefinity 3.7 site from IIS 6 to IIS 7 and upgrading Helicon URL_Rewrite_2 to Helicon Ape.

In the IIS6 environment we had a number of rewrite rules in place to redirect from /page/index.aspx to /page/ and these worked perfectly well.

This no long works now we've upgraded, and we've spent quite some time trying new things to get it working.

Helicon Ape is installed correctly, and we can get the redirects working for all non-CMS resources. We can even do a redirect from a CMS resource to an external page (i.e. Google). However, trying to redirect from a CMS resource to a page on the site is not working at all.

For example, this works fine on every page on the site

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.google.co.uk [NC,L,NS]
```

This will also redirect fine

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule images\/001\.jpg /empty.html [NC,L,NS]
```

When we do this on an page in the CMS...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule example\/index\.aspx /example [NC,L,NS]
```

...it doesn't redirect at all. It just shows the page as per usual.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try to contact HeliconTech support center and explain the problem with supporting error.log and rewrite.log for a testing request.  They are great at this kind of troubleshooting.